# How Do I Modify an EXTjs app to be 508 Compliant?

Tags: javascript, extjs, accessibility, section508

I have recently inherited a web app using the EXTjs framework.  I'm not really that familiar with it, but I have been learning it the best I can over the last few months.  I have recently been given an assignment to update the entire application to comply with 508 Compliance, that is to say, make the application accessible for those with vision issues.  I was given a deficiency list that gives examples where the software doesn't comply for various reasons.  I guess I need a little help in understanding how this works.  I've looked at the EXTjs documentation and it does say that it has accessibility features available in it, but I haven't really been successful in finding what to do.  Those using the application are using the JAWS screen reader if that makes any difference.
A few of the things I know that I need to fix are:

- Some elements need to be tagged as a heading so the screen reader can read it programmatically an to give the web page some structure.
- When tabbing around a table/grid the data is read without any context/header information.
- Color is used as a visual cue to indicate action(ie required field).  I'm supposing this is for color blindness and some other visual cue needs to be added.
- Modal windows can't be resized or moved by the keyboard.
- Needs a mechanism to bypass blocks of content that are repeated on multiple pages.
- Pages do not have titles(this is a single page app).
- Keyboard operable UI elements do not have a visible indication of focus(radio button group doesn't show focus, even if selected one does).
- Name/State of UI elements in the product can't be understood(ie the name of expand and collapse buttons are read as expand panel or collapse panel by assistive tech without context to what is being expanded or collapsed).

There are many other issues, but this gives some idea of the scope of the changes required.  As I have stated above, I've done a lot of examination of the EXTjs documentation at their site as well as google searches on how to make applications more accessible.  But I'm not really seeing what I need.  Much of this application is just configuring EXTjs templates and then loading them with much of the meat of the application being handled by the EXTjs built in js code.

I would appreciate any help, useful sites with examples, or code snippets on how to accomplish some of this.  I'm hoping that once I get started with some examples, I can just go on from there.

Thanks.

Comment: The list of things you need to fix, did that come from an accessibility review, perhaps by a third party? If so, a good accessibility review will contain information on how to **fix** the issues and not just a report of what the issues are. Your list isn't any different than most apps that need accessibility help. That is, the problems you have to fix are pretty common. You may need to hire a consultant for some guidance because that's a pretty big list for someone to spend time on for an answer. Feel free to contact me offline. Check my profile for contact info.

Comment: It sounds as though you've been given quite a massive task to update an entire application to make it accessible. Each of the accessibility failings you've listed are questions in themselves, so if you need advice on how to fix specific components then I'd suggest posting them as separate questions with reproducible code examples - i.e., "How do I create a visible focus rectangle on keyboard-operable elements?". W3C provides well-documented accessible examples for many of the components you've listed, so I'd also recommend you search for "WAI-ARIA authoring practices" as a starting point.

Comment: @slugolicious Yes, this is part of a list of things from an accessibility review that was a dozen or so pages long.  Unfortunately, it did not include any information on how to fix it.  Part of my difficulty is that I don't know the EXTjs framework very well, so it appears to me that I don't have the control over components that I would had this been a vanilla js application.

Comment: @George Yes, this is a massive task.  It is for a government agency.  I will do that search you recommend.  I will probably go ahead and post a few of those as a separate question as you suggest.  I was hoping that by posting a list of things, maybe one or two of them would be easily demonstrated and I could use that as a model for solving the rest.  I wasn't intending on getting the answer for all of them on one question but rather show different kinds of problems this project entails.  It may be that the solution to one is similar to the solution to many of them.

Comment: @brianpleshek If you're using the Ext JS framework and the framework's components are causing the issues but you can't modify them, then your options are a bit limited. You can write custom Javascript and CSS to fix the DOM layout and make the Ext JS components more accessible, but that can be quite tricky depending on how complex the components are (i.e., whether or not they're added dynamically in the DOM and how frequently they update, etc.) It may be worth showing the accessibility failings to the vendor as they may also be able to help.

Comment: The obvious benefit of stackoverflow is getting answers to your questions. A side benefit is that those posting answers can get rated on their answers and you get a bonus for when an answer is marked "accepted". In your case, @brianpleshek, it will be difficult to mark **one** answer as correct because you have so many questions in one. Even if people pick and choose which ones to answer and they have a good answer for that particular bullet point, you can't mark all of them accepted. george had a good suggestion on posting them separately. In fact, many of your points already have answers.

Comment: For example, your first Q is just adding `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc to text on the page that logically feels like a heading. It's hard to give generic advice on **what** should be a heading and what heading level to use without seeing the page. Generally you should have **one** `<h1>` and subsections should be `<h2>`, `<h3>`, etc in order. If you can't specify the H element directly, then choose the component in the library that represents a heading.

Your second Q is about using `<th scope="row|col">` so that your table has **both** row and column headers. Hopefully the library allows that.

Comment: The third Q is about WCAG 1.4.1 and whether color by itself is conveying meaning. If **all** input fields have a border and the required fields have a red border, then the only way to tell it's required is if you can see red. That would be a problem and, as you said, you'd need another visual cue (such as an asterisk in the field label, provided that there's a statement on the page that says what an asterisk means). However, if **only** required fields had a red border and optional fields didn't have a border, then you'd be ok. The fact that the field has a border indicates it's required.

Comment: Ok, last one because these should all be answers and not comments.  Q4: *"Modal windows can't be resized or moved by the keyboard."*  That's not necessarily a problem. If mouse users **can't** move the dialog, then keyboard users don't need that option either. But if the dialog **can** move moved/resized with a mouse, then, yes, you'd need the ability to do that with a keyboard too.

Answer (score 0):

Most items come with aria support. Personally I would add look into each component and add an automated aria support. E.g. button ==> aria.label = button.text

Take a look at `ariaAttributes`, `ariaDescribedBy`, `ariaLabel` and `ariaLabelledBy`. Some have `ariaErrorText`, `ariaHelp`.

Next take a look at `tabIndex`. You want to ensure that you can use TAB to jump through the fields, buttons, ...